# .Net Test Automation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests

How to generate click on link in C# for automation testing?

Answer (score 3):

if razzie assumption is true and you want to test your gui , if you are developing windows form app , use [TestComplete](http://automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete) , its perfect tools for such a use and generally test automation.

Comment: We've been pretty happy with AutomatedQA's products.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. If you want to 'unit test' your GUI, e.g., a user clicks on a link and he should navigate to page X, then I think [NUnitASP](http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html) comes close to what you want. You can basically say that you browse to page X, and can then test various things, like a textbox that should be present, what should happen when the user tries to save the form on that page, etcetera. See if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinRunner tool for automating GUI functionalities.